# Finding Terminal Velocity using Newton's Second Law & Stokes Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, projectile, drag

I've been told the terminal velocity of an small spherical object falling through a fluid can be found using this equation:

$$
v = \frac{2r^2g(\rho_s - \rho_f)}{9\eta}
$$

where $\rho_s$ is the density of the sphere and $\rho_f$ is the density of the fluid

I'm attempting to prove this using Newton's Second Law since at terminal velocity $a = 0$ therefore $\Sigma F = 0$

From my understanding, if you assume that the only three forces acting on the sphere falling are Weight of Sphere (W), Upthrust (U) and Drag (D) then $\Sigma F = W + U + D = 0$

Assuming the positive direction is in the direction of upthrust then:

$U = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \rho_fg$

$W = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \rho_s(-g)$  - I believe it should be negative g here because weight is acting in the opposite direction to upthust

$D = 6\pi \eta vr$

Therefore

$$
\Sigma F = W + U + D = 0\\
\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \rho_s(-g) + \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \rho_f g + 6\pi \eta vr = 0
\\ 2 r^2 \rho_s(-g) + 2r^2 \rho_fg + 9\eta v = 0
\\ 2r^2g(-\rho_s+\rho_f) + 9\eta v = 0
\\ 9\eta v = -2r^2g(-\rho_s+\rho_f)
\\ 9\eta v = 2r^2g(\rho_s-\rho_f)
\\ v = \frac{2r^2g(\rho_s-\rho_f)}{9\eta}
$$

Hence it appears true but what confuses me is that when the object moves in the direction of weight you get a positive velocity but weight acting in the same direction is negative. Why is this correct or more likely where have I made a mistake?

Comment: When you have this kinds of confusion  it is usually a sign that you have ignored your own sign conventions somewhere. You've been careful to talk about those conventions as applied to weight and buoyant force (what you're calling "upthrust"), but what about drag? (You may also be the victim of many sources which treat the direction of drag using vectors, but in words.)

Comment: Terminal,velocity is unaffected by friction?  Or is friction a function of density?

Comment: @WGroleau I'm not sure I get your comment. The viscosity of the fluid $\eta$ and the size of the falling object $r$ both appear in the result.

Comment: So viscosity and friction are the same?  Or one depends on the other?

Comment: @WGroleau One can—in casual language—call fluid drag (which is quantified here in terms of viscosity) a kind of friction. Some people would prefer to make a strong distinctions between them, but they are certainly both dissipative effects that act to counter relative motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to be careful with the fact that forces are indeed vectors! It is then important to define the orientation of the reference frame first. In the example below I decided to call the vertical $y$ the axis coming vertical from the top down.

[image]

Newton's second law then becomes

$$
\vec{W} + \vec{U} + \vec{D} = \left(\frac{4}{3}\pi\rho_s r^3 g \right)(\color{orange}{+}\hat{y}) + \left(\frac{4}{3}\pi\rho_f r^3 g \right)(\color{orange}{-}\hat{y}) + 6\pi \eta |v| r (\color{orange}{-}\hat{y}) = 0
$$

From this you can recover you equation.

NOTE: You can flip the orientation of the axis and the result is the same ([should be the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_invariance))

Comment: I find that the historical practice of treating drag in terms of speed instead of using $\vec{D} = -6 \pi \eta \vec{v} r$ adds to the confusion here. The OP had all the forces pointed in the right direction to start with, but he didn't have explicit absolute value signs on the velocity which left the raw math with no way of express "and you have to chose the direction of motion correctly".

Comment: @dmckee You are absolutely correct, that's why I made de $|v|$ explicit, hopefully it will not contribute to the confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider all quantities as vector elements or as moduli that come from moduli of vector elements. So, the first equation you put is actually wrong...
You have to take, say $\sum \vec{F} = \vec{0}$ which gives place to $\vec{W}+\vec{U} + \vec{D}= \vec{0}$, and further $-W+U+D=0$, being the elements without vector symbol the modulus, positive definite. If you accept $W,U,D$ as the moduli of the forces, positive definite, then the equation $W+U+D=0$ is obviously wrong. To correct it, you put the notion of direction of the vectors in the equation introducing "minus" for the forces in a given direction and "plus" in the contrary. In this case, all elements that come into that forces are also positive definite. (So $g$ instead of $-g$).